# Notify user history scheme design

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to notify user when the service down and up and this is my design now (just for demo).

```
service
{
    id,
    name,
    isActive
}

history
{
    id,
    serviceId,
    upTime,
    downTime
}
```

When service down I will add a record to history with downTime and upTime is NULL. Until service up I will find the last history with relative serviceId 
and update the upTime. I do not know it is a right design or not. Maybe separate to two records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to separate that becomes two records. And I would like to add Comment field that will explain about the problem why the services are down or how do you repair to restore the services.

The schema would be like

```
Table History

HistoryID int,
ServiceID int,
Status varchar(4),
StatusTime datetime2(3),
Comment varchar(50)
```

Then, the Data would be like

```
HistoryID   ServiceID     Status       StatusTime               Comment
1               1         Down         2016-05-03 00:00:00      Problem happens because xxx
2               1         Up           2016-05-04 00:00:00      Restart the service
```

*EDIT
if you want to show something like :

ServiceID: 1 donwtime:2016/05/03 uptime:2016/05/04.

you could use your schema to make the select statement easier. but I still recommend using Comment to let you know what cause the service down, and how can u fix it. It would make it better for maintaining your service. And you can insert a new row for each Down status, and update the last row for Up status.
for example :

```
HistoryID ServiceID  DownTime UpTime  DownComment UpComment
    1         1         xxx    xxx       xxx         xxx
    2         1         xxx    NULL      xxx         NULL
```

first row means the service was already repaired and went UP at xxx time. second row means the service went down again, but hasnt been repaired.

Comment: In this scheme how to display the history record if you have many same serviceID up and down record

Comment: @MichaelMao How do you want to display your History Records? If you want to show only the last record, then you could just select with the `max(StatusTime)`. Or if you want to display all the records for 1 ServiceID, then you can select it and `group by ServiceID` (to check how may times this service have down).

Comment: Something like ServiceID: 1 donwtime:2016/05/03 uptime:2016/05/04. A full display need down and up time but one service may down and up many times.

Comment: @MichaelMao how the Schema built depends on how do you fetch the records and how do you want to display it. because u didnt state clearly how you want to display your records or how often will this Down and Up condition occurs, But, please notice that I add DownComment and UpComment in there, to let you know in the future what cause the down problem and how to solve it.

Comment: I have a question if I had a down record and now the service up. How to find this down record and update it's uptime.I think I can select the last record which uptime is null and update it. But is it a good way? This is what I ask in the origin question. BTW I know how to write that code my concern is this design is right. And thank you for your help. Very appreciate